# Java. Нужна помощь в рефакторинге слишком большого класса

Tags: java, ооп

У меня игра крестики нолики и в ней есть класс который описывает партию от начала до конца. Мне кажется он великоват, но я не как не могу решить что от туда вынести, за что не возьмусь и находится причина по которой оно тут вроде должно быть.

```
// описывает партию
public class Game implements Play {
    // объект утилитного класса в который вынесена проверка наличия победителя
    private Validation validation = new ValidationWinnerUtil();
    // игроки
    private Subject[] gamers = new Subject[2];
    // ввод с консоли
    private Input input;
    // побелитель данной партии
    private Subject win;
    // доска для игры
    private Desk board;

    public Game(Input input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    // устанавливает размер доски
    private void initBoard() {
        System.out.println("Хотите использовать стандартный размер доски 3х3 (y/n)?");
        String answer = this.input.getString();
        if (answer.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Введите размер доски :");
            this.board = new Board(this.input.getNumber());
        } else if (answer.equals("y")) {
            this.board = new Board(3);
        } else {
            initBoard();
        }
    }

    // for test
    Subject[] getGamers() {
        return gamers;
    }

    // for test
    Desk getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    // инициализирует массив с игроками. порядок меняется в зависимости от того кто
    // ходит первым. кто первый тот играет крестиками.
    @Override
    public void choiceSide() {
        System.out.println("Кто ходит первый: (Bot / I) :");
        String answer = this.input.getString().toLowerCase();
        if (answer.equals("i")) {
            this.gamers[0] = new User(Cell.X, "user");
            this.gamers[1] = new User(Cell.O, "bot");
        } else if (answer.equals("bot")){
            this.gamers[0] = new User(Cell.X, "bot");
            this.gamers[1] = new User(Cell.O, "user");
        } else {
            choiceSide();
        }
    }

    // зацикливает очередность ходов игроков
    @Override
    public void loopMove() {
        this.initBoard();
        PrinterBoard.printDesc(board.getBoard());
        while (validation.gameCanGoOn(board.getBoard())) {
            for (Subject subject : this.gamers) {
                try {
                    if (validation.gameCanGoOn(board.getBoard())
                            ) {

                        board.move(subject.getColor(), getNewPosition(subject));
                        PrinterBoard.printDesc(board.getBoard());
                        this.win = subject;
                    }
                } catch (IllegalMove illegalMove) {
                    illegalMove.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // дает новую позицию для хода если бот то генерирует в классе AutomaticMove
    // если пользователь то с консоли принимает
    private Position getNewPosition(Subject subject) {
        if (subject.getName().equals("user")) {
            System.out.println("По вертикали:");
            int y = this.input.getNumber();
            System.out.println("По горизонтали:");
            return new Position(this.input.getNumber(), y);
        } else {
            return new AutomaticMove().generateMove(this.board);
        }
    }

    // в момент когда игра продолжаться не может смотрит есть ли победитель если да то записывает его в поле win
    @Override
    public Subject initWinner() {
        if (!this.validation.emptyCellExist(board.getBoard()) &&
                !this.validation.winnerDetermines(board.getBoard())) {
            System.out.println("Ничья");
            return new User(Cell.EMPTY, "nobody");
        } else {
            System.out.println(format("Победитель: %s", this.win.getColor()));
            return this.win;
        }
    }
    }

Вот тесты к нему:

    @Test
    public void whenUserMoveFirstThenUserAddInArrGamersFirst() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"i"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[]{3});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        assertThat(game.getGamers()[0].getName(), is("user"));
        assertThat(game.getGamers()[1].getName(), is("bot"));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenBotMoveFirstThenUserAddInArrFirst() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"bot"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {3});
        Game game = new Game(input);

        game.choiceSide();
        assertThat(game.getGamers()[0].getName(), is("bot"));
        assertThat(game.getGamers()[1].getName(), is("user"));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenBotMoveFirstAndWinByHorizontalThen() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"bot", "y"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {2, 0, 2, 1});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        game.loopMove();
        Subject subject = game.initWinner();
        assertThat(subject.getName(), is("bot"));
        assertThat(subject.getColor(), is(Cell.X));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenManMoveFirstAndWinByHorizontalThen() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"I", "y"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        game.loopMove();
        Subject subject = game.initWinner();
        assertThat(subject.getName(), is("user"));
        assertThat(subject.getColor(), is(Cell.X));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenManMoveFirstAndWinByVerticalThen() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"I", "y"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        game.loopMove();
        Subject subject = game.initWinner();
        assertThat(subject.getName(), is("user"));
        assertThat(subject.getColor(), is(Cell.X));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenBotMoveSecondAndWinByVerticalThen() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"I", "y"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        game.loopMove();
        Subject subject = game.initWinner();
        assertThat(subject.getName(), is("bot"));
        assertThat(subject.getColor(), is(Cell.O));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenManMoveFirstAndWinByDiagonalLeftUpToRightDownThen() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"I", "y"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        game.loopMove();
        Subject subject = game.initWinner();
        assertThat(subject.getName(), is("user"));
        assertThat(subject.getColor(), is(Cell.X));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenManMoveSecondAndWinByDiagonalRightUpToLeftDownThen() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"bot", "y"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        game.loopMove();
        Subject subject = game.initWinner();
        assertThat(subject.getName(), is("user"));
        assertThat(subject.getColor(), is(Cell.O));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenUseNonstandardSizeDescThenSizeItIsChoiceUser() {
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {"bot", "n"});
        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1});
        Game game = new Game(input);
        game.choiceSide();

        game.loopMove();
        assertThat(game.getBoard().getBoard().length, is(4));
    }
```

На первый взгляд как мне кажется надо вынести определение размера доски, но если я вынесу `initBoard()` то у меня от `Input` будут зависеть уже несколько классов(а не только `Game`), и начнуться проблемы с тестированием. Та же проблема и с `getNewPosition(Subject subject)` тоже нужен ввод с консоли. Ну такие методы как `initWinner()` - определение победителя, `loopMove()` - зацикливание ходов до какого-то конца игры, или `choiceSide()` - выбор кто ходит первым я не рассматриваю на вынос из этого класса они явно относятся к партии. Ведь партия в этом и заключается что: выбрали кто за кого, провели сами ходы, определили победителя.

В общем такая дилемма. Подскажите как быть?

Проблема в том что мне надо чтобы от ввода с консоли зависел только 1 класс но при этом у меня в этот класс попадают и другие методы которы не вписываются в общую тематику данного класса.

возможный пример:

В классе игры на пример метод:

```
 private Dialogs dialogs = new Dialogs();

    private void initBoard() {
        String answer = this.dialogs.ask("Хотите использовать стандартный размер доски 3х3 (y/n)?");
        if (answer.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Введите размер доски :");
            this.board = new Board(this.input.getNumber());
        } else if (answer.equals("y")) {
            this.board = new Board(3);
        } else {
            initBoard();
        }
    }
```

И класс который инкапсулирует ввод:

```
public class Dialogs {
    private Input input = new ConsoleInput();

    public void setInput(Input input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String ask(String question) {
        System.out.println(question);
        return this.input.getString();
    }

    public int askPosition(String question) {
        System.out.println(question);
        return this.input.getNumber();
    }
```

Comment: Вообще не смешивайте ввод с консоли и ваш класс. Инкапсулируйте работу с консолью в отдельный класс, отвяжите от этого. И вы сможете отделить и `initBoard` и все прочее. Т.к. вам не надо будет "задавать вопросы" по ходу инициализации

Comment: >>>Вообще не смешивайте ввод с консоли и ваш класс.<<< А как именно? Можете маленький пример на один метод показать? Вы имеете в виду вынести только вопросы и ввод? или методы целиком?

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы приведенный в вашем примере класс манипулировал уже данными полученными от пользователя. представьте к примеру, что следующим этапом будет добавление GUI, тогда вам придется вносить исправления непосредственно в ваш класс. В идеале же ваш класс не надо будет переписывать.

Comment: Типо такого? Добавил в конец вопроса как возможный пример

Comment: скорее всего ваш класс Dialog, должен иметь один метод типа getDimension который вернет вам размерность доски, всю остальную работу по опросу пользователя, проверки валидности введенных данных, должна оставаться внутри того класса, тогда ваш initBoard сведется к new Board(dialog.getDimension); Вот такая идея. Подробней, просто сейчас нет времени :)

Comment: Ну тогда я в принципе правильно же написал... просто я ему тогда уже и вопросы с получением данных для хода тоже поручил а то получится несколько классов зависящих от input тоже плохо. Спасибо большое за подсказку!

Comment: В целом, да. Просто вам надо максимально отвязать этот класс от связи с вводом-выводом. Это, как бы сказать более низкоуровневая работа в вашем контексте. Это, конечно, наверняка не весь рефакторинг, но как только отвяжетесь от такой низкоуровневой работы, мне кажется, в дальнейшем у вас просто более развяжутся руки для  дальнейшего рефакторинга.

Comment: Спасибо. Я все понял.

Comment: у вас геттеры для тестов - точно не нужны. такие вещи можно протестовать при помощи mock.

Comment: а что такое mock нельзя ли строчку кода и смысл идеи в двух словах?

Comment: @Sublihim оформили бы ответом все свои комментарии.

Comment: @andreycha, эх, да хорошо бы, конечно.. надо заняться на досуге.